# php get date from now every 1 year between two dates

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to get the date every 1 year or any variable interval between two dates. My dates examples are as follows.  It just seems to run forever and I cant make it work and it doesn't print anything out at the end.

```
$currentDate = '2014-04-15';
$endDate = '2018-04-15';
$reminder = '+1 year';

 $dateArray = array();

    while($currentDate <= $endDate){
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($reminder, strtotime($currentDate)));
    array_push($dateArray, $currentDate);
    }
    print_r($dateArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change

```
$dateArray = array_push($dateArray, $currentDate);
```

to

```
array_push($dateArray, $currentDate);
```

Because array_push, returns boolean and next time, you call this function, it tries to store string in the int/boolean type and cause error.

Comment: thanks @Andriy yes that was a silly mistake.  I changed that however its still not printing out any results.

Comment: Try to enable error output, or view the logs. I've tried your code in online tester, and it works as expected. Returning 
Array ( [0] => 2015-04-15 [1] => 2016-04-15 [2] => 2017-04-15 [3] => 2018-04-15 [4] => 2019-04-15 )

Comment: awesome.  Thanks @Andriy and everyone who helped.  It would appear I wasn't echoing a $reminderP value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateInterval class and DateTime::Add() method:

```
    $begin_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2014-04-15');
    $end_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2018-04-15');

    $res_array = array();

    while ($begin_date < $end_date)
    {
        $begin_date->Add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 year'));
        $res_array[] = clone($begin_date);
    }
    echo ("<pre>"); print_r($res_array); echo ("</pre>");
```

Thats the Object oriented style.